# How many solutions of the equation $[f'(x)]^2=f(x)\cdot f''(x)$.

Tags: calculus, roots

[image]
A function of degree 4 has the graph as shown.
How many solutions of the equation $[f'(x)]^2=f(x)\cdot f''(x)$.
The answer is $0$ solution. I have tried to express as: 
$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\int\frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}dx$$
Which gives $\ln|\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}|=C$. But I found no relation to the answer.
Hope your kind help!

Comment: What's the unknown?

Comment: "The answer is 0 solution." Maybe I'm misreading this but why wouldn't $e^x$ work? Or are we only looking for 4th degree polynomials that would solve this?

Comment: it's f' on the right side denominator

Comment: yes, we need to find point $x$ that make the equation true!

Comment: @Brenton The question isn't asking to solve the differential equation. f(x) is *known* and is the quartic function shown in the graph. The question is: If you plug in f(x) in the above equation, the resulting polynomial equation is $x$ has how many solutions?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for points where
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln|f(x)|=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{f(x)f''(x)-f'(x)^2}{f'(x)^2}=0
$$
But for a polynomial of degree $4$ with $4$ distinct roots, $f(x)=a\prod_{k=1}^4(x-x_k)$, you get
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln|f(x)|=\sum_{k=1}^4\frac{1}{(x-x_k)^2}
$$

which is always positive or infinite as sum of squares.

Comment: +1 Very clever.